# How to make initialization in only one instance in multi-instance Azure Cloud Service Classic?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-web-app-service

I have 1 web role. I run initialization code on startup. Now I want to have N instances but I want only one of them to run the initialization code and all others to wait.

Looks to me like master-node - slave-nodes.

How can I achieve this? Is there any known pattern for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought this problem is solved long ago by [Alexandre Brisebois](https://github.com/brisebois).

By combining two of his classes [Blob lease manager](https://github.com/brisebois/Brisebois.WindowsAzure/blob/master/Brisebois.WindowsAzure.Storage/Blobs/BlobLeaseManager.cs) and [Job Reservation Service](https://github.com/brisebois/Brisebois.WindowsAzure/blob/master/Brisebois.WindowsAzure.Storage/Blobs/JobReservationService.cs) he explained it all in two blog posts :

1. [About leasing a blob](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/09/08/dont-be-fooled-blob-lease-management-is-tricky-business/)
2. [About scheduling and reserving slot for a distributed job](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/09/10/preventing-jobs-from-running-simultaneously-on-multiple-role-instances/)

I know that Link answers are not preferred on SO but pasting all the coded needed and explaining it here will not be a good idea either.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way for all instances to wait while one is doing some work is to have the master instance place a [lease on a blob in Azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/lease-blob).
The master instance's WorkerRole.cs upon startup creates a blob file in some Azure container with a lease on it.  Releases the lease when it is done initializing.
Slave instances attempt to read the same file in the during startup and wait until the lease is released.  if it is released, the blob file should contain some sort of an indication that initialization was complete

Do you know which instance of a Cloud Role you want to be the master?  Is it the first one that boots up, or the first alphabetical one?
If it is the first one that boots up, problem is simpler - as each instance should try to create/lease the file and all but one will fail.

If it is the first alphabetical one, then examine RoleEnvironment.Instance.Id (going from memory) and have it spin up initilization code if it is the "RoleName_IN_1" only

Since instances can reboot arbitrarily, do ensure that they do not try to re-initialize - you will need to think on how to best handle it - probably by putting some sort of a timestamp into the blob file.

Comment: The problem arises with the "instance should try to create/lease the file and all but one will fail." - it is not true because instance N may spawn after the whole initialization is complete and it does not know it - if the initialization is complete already or it is the first instance that should do it - the initialization file is there and it is not locked too because the first instance to come has done the job and released the file. This is possible since the instances are spawned only after the first request. 

I need something which identifies the restart of the service itself.

Comment: If there is a common service storage or a "reliable dictionary" or anything common between the RoleEntryPoints which is erased / reinstantiated on every service restart outside of the environment will do the job.